# Generics and wildcards on a RecyclerView.Adapter implementations

Tags: java, android, generics

I am trying to implement a custom Adapter for RecyclerView without using a single cast or instanceof.

My implementation is heavily inspired by [this article](https://medium.com/@dpreussler/writing-better-adapters-1b09758407d2#.34ow62av7).

My adapter should be able to display any item of the following type :

```
public interface InboxVisitable {
    int getType(InboxTypeFactory inboxTypeFactory);
}
```

I have 2 implementations of this type :

```
public class InboxMonthViewModel implements SentInboxFragment.InboxVisitable {
    public String month;

    @Override
    public int getType(SentInboxFragment.InboxTypeFactory inboxTypeFactory) {
        return inboxTypeFactory.getType(this);
    }
}

public class InboxMessageViewModel implements SentInboxFragment.InboxVisitable {
    public String message;

    @Override
    public int getType(SentInboxFragment.InboxTypeFactory inboxTypeFactory) {
        return inboxTypeFactory.getType(this);
    }
}
```

The InboxFactoryType is a factory to link a specific type to a unique id used by the adapter to determine the view type :

```
public static class InboxTypeFactory {
    public int getType(InboxMessageViewModel message) {
        return R.layout.cell_inbox_message;
    }

    public int getType(InboxMonthViewModel month) {
        return R.layout.cell_inbox_message;
    }

    public InboxViewHolder getViewHolderForType(View itemView, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == R.layout.cell_inbox_message) {
            return new InboxMessageViewHolder(itemView);
        } else {
            return new InboxMonthViewHolder(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the factory is also responsible of creating the view holder for each possible types.

The View Holder is a generic view holder because the adapter needs to know only 1 type of holder :

```
private static abstract class InboxViewHolder<T extends InboxVisitable> extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public InboxViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
    public abstract void bind(T data);
}
```

And, as I have 2 types of data, I have 2 corresponding view holders :

```
private static class InboxMessageViewHolder extends InboxViewHolder<InboxMessageViewModel> {

    public InboxMessageViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void bind(InboxMessageViewModel data) {
        // do stuff
        data.message;
    }
}

private static class InboxMonthViewHolder extends InboxViewHolder<InboxMonthViewModel> {

    public InboxMonthViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void bind(InboxMonthViewModel data) {
        // do stuff
        data.month;
    }
}
```

Now, for the fun part, the Adapter.
He is using the factory for getting the proper view type for each specific data type and with this factory, he will also create the view holders for each data.
The Adapter is holding a list of the most generic type of data he is manipulating : `InboxVisitable`.

```
private static class InboxAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InboxViewHolder> {

    private final InboxTypeFactory inboxTypeFactory;
    List<InboxVisitable> itemList;

    InboxAdapter() {
        inboxTypeFactory = new InboxTypeFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public InboxViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                                            .inflate(viewType, parent, false);
        return inboxTypeFactory.getViewHolderForType(itemView, viewType);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(InboxViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //noinspection unchecked
        holder.bind(itemList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly but it has a minor flaw : when binding the view holder, the compiler tells me that there is an unchecked cast when I give an `InboxVisitable` to the `bind(T)` method.

I tried to add to specify the adaper `RecyclerView.Adapter<InboxViewHolder<? extends InboxVisitable>>` (and reflecting the specification everywhere) but with this, the `bind()` expect a `? extends InboxVisitable` but I'm only providing him a `InboxVisitable`.

How can I work around all this generic madness to have no cast, no instanceof and no unchecked call to this `bind()` method ?

Thank you very much,
Pierre

Comment: From the code you posted, it doesn't seem like you even need to be using generics. Why does `bind()` care about whether `T` is `InboxMessageViewModel` or `InboxMessageViewModel`. Both classes simply implement the interface `InboxVisitable`. You can just do `public abstract void bind(InboxVisitable data);` without the generics. Unless of course, those two classes do more than implement that interface. In which case `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` might be the only solution.

Comment: I forgot to add some code in both implementations of `InboxVisitable`. They both contains specific contents that needs to be accessible inside the specifics `ViewHolders`. I have edited the code.

Comment: use one common `ViewHolder`, how many types do you expect to have? 100s? 1000s? or just two or three?

Comment: I have max 3 types but if this is properly done, this could be very generic and handles as many types as wanted.